# Graphic Design self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Answer (score 4):

[How to change smart object outlines and colors?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8729/how-to-change-smart-object-outlines-and-colors)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question + 1st answer surely deserved more votes in my opinion. Not a lot of visits, but food format for a technical Q&A 'database'

Comment: Upvoted the question, the answer, and scott's additional comment

Answer (score 3):

[Toggle visibility of only one of a group of layers?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/toggle-visibility-of-only-one-of-a-group-of-layers)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: No idea what the question is talking about with "solos" one of them and have no way to in turn know what the answer means. I can only assume its something about apps which I don't do. Question should be amended probably but I don't know to what.

Comment: @ryan I think the guy is using 'to solo layer X' to mean 'to isolate' or 'to hide everything except layer X'. Not a term I've heard before. Could be a lost-in-translation thing, by their username I'd guess English is their second language.

Comment: I thought that but the answer wouldn't make sense if it means visibility. Unless I'm just really lost on the answer as well.

Comment: The guy has several layer groups. He wants to hide everything in layer group X except one layer, without changing the visibility of other layer groups.

Answer (score 3):

[How to convert .mp4 to vector animation in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8774/how-to-convert-mp4-to-vector-animation-in-illustrator)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Interesting. Answer is good, but it would also be useful to see 'alternatives' to illustrator since it can't be done in it (I know it wouldn't answer the question, but it would be, as I said, useful).

Comment: I like the question and the answer. Upvoted both

Answer (score 2):

[How can I export an image from Illustrator image at multiple sizes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8659/how-can-i-save-an-adobe-illustrator-image-in-multiple-sizes)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I'm not reading 5 paragraphs to ask how to save an image to a certain size. Just being honest here. Short and to the point, especially in the questions. Let the answers get detailed.

Comment: Agreed. Context in questions and proof of prior research are great, but shouldn't get in the way of the actual question. I'd edit it to have "In Illustrator, how do I save a raster image (jpg, gif, png) of a specific size in pixels?", then a line, then all the other stuff which people can read or skip at their leisure.

Answer (score 1):

[Placing images in Illustrator CS5](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8685/placing-images-in-illustrator-cs5)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Could also use a title editing, since it doesn't really say anything about the problem. Good one though

Comment: Agree with Yisela, the question needs changing. Also the bullet points are worthless back story that just confuse people (confused me even with all those numbers). All it really needs to ask is "Why are image resolutions differing between AI and PS and what do I need to do to keep file sizes down while working in print?" or something along those lines. It's not a coding question so the resolutions are merely fluff and hold no relevance on the outcome.

Comment: @Ryan edited! (more than 1000 characters, a new personal record). Could be improved, though, so go ahead if you think of any further simplification.

Answer (score 1):

[Aligning button backgrounds to pixel boundaries in photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8713/creating-button-backgrounds-in-photoshop)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Title is not correct, should address positions (but editing would result in this question changing here too?)

Comment: @yisela Don't be afraid to edit questions on the main site to make them better. That's exactly the kind of thing these evaluations are supposed to encourage. :)

Comment: I usually try to edit titles, but because this one is in this particular question I thought maybe it should wait until the evaluation is finished...

Comment: When done with this eval it should probably be renamed to something like, "How to adjust the snap to incrementation" so that people can find it easier. The user could also mark their own response as 'Answer'

Answer (score 1):

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8795/can-you-identify-this-font-in-an-image

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1, I find that the background story behind the question teaches a hard learned lesson about documenting your designs for your future self.

Comment: another worthless Font Identification question IMO. Given that nobody can ever search for the font name since that's what they're looking for these will never prove useful to future beginners

Comment: @ryan It's true that font identification questions are often (not always, e.g. http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=david+guetta+t-shirt+font ) unsearchable, and this one is. But that != worthless, because google searches aren't the only way to find content. For designers who are interested in new fonts (not all are - I'm not particularly - but many are), font identification questions are a) a reason to come back to the site (a drip-feed of new non-overused fonts good enough for people to want to ask about them) and b) an easy (for some people fun) way to interact with the site and get involved.

Comment: And as with any topic, people not interested in font identification can set the 'font-identification' tag to "ignore". Thinking about it, we can make font questions that are based on published designs more useful and searchable by making sure appropriate search terms are there - e.g. the slogan on the t-shirt in that David Guetta one. Editted...

Answer (score 1):

[Photoshop Marquee Tool - Lost square corners](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8764/photoshop-marquee-tool-lost-square-corners)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Again should probably changed so the question is something along the lines of, "Why are the corners of my rectangular marquee tool rounded and how can I change it back to square?" so that people can find it. And once again the 1 shot user could have hit "answered"

Answer (score 1):

[Problem opening pattern file in photoshop cs5](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8788/problem-opening-pattern-file-in-photoshop-cs5)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Maybe adding something in the question and title about it being a subtle texture pattern not showing up would help but I kinda take it the same as font identification question - not much use to anyone else

Answer (score 1):

[Problem printing Booklet in Indesign to a PDF using postscript](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8751/problem-printing-booklet-in-indesign-to-a-pdf-using-postscript)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Very specific but good for technical Q&A

Comment: Answer simply redirects to another website, and websites tend to die every now and then. A quick explanation about the solution might be useful in this case.

Comment: Really good question, comments, and answer. Agree with Hrulga that it could be posted as an answer and once again the one time user could mark the answer as such.